# ? Statements in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I've been having some trouble understanding some Verilog code I'm trying to rewrite. Specifically this line:

```
assign x = (y) ? a | b | c : 1'b0;
```

I think it's an if-statement, but I'm still not entirely sure how it works, so any help translating would be great!

Answer (score 1):

this is the **ternary operator** with semantics similar to other programming languages. it can *roughly* be thought as an `if` statment:

```
if (y) 
     x = a | b | c;
else 
     x = 1'b0;
```

though in verilog  it is **not** an exact substitution because it also does specific functionality in presence of 'x's.

Answer (score 0):

It would indeed be an if-else statement that would implement a mux. You can view this code as follows

[image: How this would synthesize]